# sequential loop in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a data set with the following variables (Segment, Quantity and Price).
What I need is to compute the sum of “Quantity” and the average “Price” for every segment, up until the last Segment in the series, as shown in the example.
I tried different approaches with DO IF, LOOP and LAG but unsuccessfully. Thanks!

Segment Cuantity    Price   Sum_Quantity    Average_Prrice

1   4   20
1   5   10
1   1   20
1   4   10
1   3   20  17  16

2   6   40
2   9   20
2   23  30  38  30

1   4   30
1   6   20  10  25

2   15  15
2   12  20
2   3   10  30  15

...

Answer (score 1):

Look up [AGGREGATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_aggregate.htm)

To add the SUM and MEAN as variables into the existing dataset:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* /BREAK=SEGMENT
 /Sum_Quantity=SUM(Quantity)
 /Ave_Price=MEAN(Price).
```

Alternatively, to create as new dataset:

```
DATESET DECLARE dsAgg.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=dsAgg /BREAK=SEGMENT
 /Sum_Quantity=SUM(Quantity)
 /Ave_Price=MEAN(Price).
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but the effect is not the desire one... Each line in the file is over time (e.g. every second) and segment is always 1 or 2 (and is never the same length of time). Although I want to “Break” AGGREGATE every time segment change (from 1-to-2 or 2-to-1), AGGREGATE is just giving me the SUM and the MEAN of ALL segment 1 and ALL segment 2, for the entire file…

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to describe (not to me anyway) to be able to help further in anyway.

Comment: Jignesh, I got the solution by creating a new variable (changestate):                     SORT CASES BY timevariable segmentvariable. 
IF $CASENUM EQ 1 changestate = 1. 
IF $CASENUM GT 1 AND segmentvariable EQ LAG(segmentvariable) changestate =LAG(changestate ). 
IF $CASENUM GT 1 AND segmentvariable NE LAG(segmentvariable) changestate =LAG(changestate )+1. 
DATASET DECLARE agg. 
AGGREGATE OUTFILE agg / BREAK changestate / Mean_Qty=MEAN(quantity). Thank you!

Comment: If you explain your problem more clearly, it give others a better chance to provide any help as your original post mentions not time variant variable? Anyhows, why don't you just to do: 


AGGREGATE OUTFILE agg / BREAK timevariable segmentvariable / Mean_Qty=MEAN(quantity).